# Event handling in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, why isn't the following custom event not firing?

```vb
Public Class classes1
    Public Event buttonload(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)        Handles Button2.Click
        attd.Show()
        RaiseEvent buttonload(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class attd
    Dim WithEvents c1 As New classes1
    Sub c1_buttonload(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles c1.buttonload
        MsgBox("Event received")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: explain your requirement more properly...

Answer (score 1):

You are using your first form, `classes1`, to show your second form, `attd`, and then raise your CustomEvent. Then in your second form, `attd`, you are creating another instance of the first form, `classes1`, and then trying to attach your handler to that instance's event. They are **not the same**, so it will not fire.

It is really not clear exactly what you are trying to do. If you are just experimenting around with events you can try something like this.

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim attd As Form2 = New Form2
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        attd.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        AddHandler attd.buttonload, AddressOf buttonLoadHandler
    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonLoadHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MsgBox("Event received")
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Event buttonload(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent buttonload(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you are just wanting to have your second Form respond to the First Forms Button Click try something like this.

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim attd As Form2 = New Form2
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        attd.Show()
        attd.showMessageBox()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub showMessageBox()
        MsgBox("Hello World")
    End Sub
End Class
```